# Authenticate service for both applications and API microservices

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, react-native, microservices

I have a `node` server with express for a SaaS application. The `node`/`express` application serves the company landing page, registering or users, authentication, user and password changes. This is all build with `node`/expr`e`ss. Authentication is done using `passport`.

When the user logs in, he is redirected to a dashboard application (the SaaS app itself) built with `React`, `react-route` and `Redux`. `Redux` needs to call the `node`/`express` API, that is currently in the same `node`/`express` service.

The APIs are also going to be used by a mobile app to be developed using `React Native`.

We want to split the services into different node modules, one for the SaaS application and another to handle the company page, registering, etc. A movement towards microservices architecture.

Our doubt is how to handle user authentication. We need a single authentication mechanism that will allow the user to use the `React` SaaS app and also that will serve the mobile app.

If the user is logged in from the web, he can use the SaaS app with the API. If he is logged from the mobile, he can use the API from the mobile.

This is our first approach to splitting the server and would like to find out the recommended method to solve the authentication problem. Naturally if we could split the authentication service as another microservice that would be very interesting.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Have you considered using JWT?

Comment: Not yet aware of. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the authentication providers that do this sort of thing for a living. [auth0](https://auth0.com/) and [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/) are two examples, but there are many more.

Use their API's to setup an app and plug it into express. After going through this process you'll have a better idea of what features you might need and what you would need to implement in an API to use them.

At the end of the review, either use one of the services or implement a cut down version of the features you need with [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/).

Comment: Seens that Auth0 solves all the authentication problems, but I could not find out how to authenticate once in for multiple systems. Shall I store a JWT and pass it when calling the availanle applications - like the SaaS application ?

Answer (score 1):

One way I have solved this particular problem is by using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and JWT.

Users log in using [Auth0 Lock](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock) and after that my web app stores a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) in local storage. This gets passed in the header of each ajax request to the server. The server is responsible for validating the JWT on each request. In order to roll this out for a React Native app, the same approach can be used with the [react-native-lock](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock).

In regards specifically to Passport it looks that there are [JWT libs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) which might mean that you don't need to rely on something like Auth0.